# C: Character input with scanf

Tags: c, character, scanf

I have a simple program that raises a floating point number x to the power of and in integer n. I added a while loop to repeat the process providing the appropriate input (here 'Y' as yes). However, when I type in any any character at scanf(" %c",anwser); the program fails and closes. Any idea?

```
float x;
 char *anwser='Y';
 int n,k;
 while (anwser=='Y'){
   printf("Give floating point number x to be raised at the power of n \n ");
   scanf("%f%d",&x,&n);
   printf(" \n result : %f",power(x,n));
   printf("\nDo again?? ");
   scanf(" %c",anwser);
  }

float power(float x , int n){
     int i;
     float pow=1;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) pow*=x;
     return pow;
}
```

Comment: 'Y' is a literal constant, which means you cannot write to it.  You try to do that in scanf.  Instead use a writable  char and initialize it to 'Y'.

Comment: Aside: always use `double` unless your environment is stuck in 20th century. Unfortunately there is textbook legacy so old it pre-dates `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `char*` to store just a char like `'Y'`.
Here is your working code, with little mods:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     double base;
     size_t exp;
     double res = 1;
     char answer;
     do {
         printf("Give floating point number x to be raised at the power of n: \n");
         scanf(" %lf%zu", &base, &exp);
         for (size_t i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
             res *= base;
         }
         printf("Result: %lf\n", res);
         printf("Do you want repeat? (y/Y or n/N)\n");
         scanf(" %c", &answer);
         res = 1;
     }while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: cool, but a little explanation on the "why" side would be much better, IMHO.